# Android Studio, не запускается виртуалка

Tags: android-studio

Всем привет. Установил виртуальный девайс Nexus 5, пытаюсь его запустить, но выдает это:

```
2:35 Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
2:35 Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

Как это фиксить? Буду рад любому ответу на вопрос.

Comment: Процессор какой?

Answer (score 1):

Сталкивался с проблемой,когда все виртуальные девайсы наотрез отказывались запускаться...в моём случае,эта проблема была в том,что была отключена виртуализация...подробней,как её включить,прочтите здесь [intel virtualization technology](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/ru/articles/115003910391-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-VT-x-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%9F%D0%9A-),при условии,что процессор у вас от Intel!Но не забудьте перед этим установить в SDK Manager *Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator* , про это вы можете тоже найти инструкцию в интернете!